# Where is there a canned disparity image to point cloud function?

Tags: ros, image, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

e.g.

giveMeAPointCloud( disparity_image, camera_info, *point_cloud)

where cloud is the output. I don't really care whether cloud is pcl::PointCloud or sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.

Is this nicely exposed and available somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9687/where-is-there-a-canned-disparity-image-to-point-cloud-function?/) by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 573 on 2011-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no direct library call to do that currently, but you can use the [stereo_image_proc/PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc#stereo_image_proc.2BAC8-diamondback.stereo_image_proc.2BAC8-point_cloud2) nodelet. If you really need to just call a function, you can look at the [source code](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/stereo_image_proc/html/point__cloud2_8cpp_source.html#l00142). This creates a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0